# Checking Users credentials against AD while they are logged in

Tags: single-sign-on, apex-webservice, activedirectory

I am looking to get some suggestions on the best solution for following requirement. Any help will be appreciated.

Requirement is to capture user's name using their AD credentials (they will be asked to enter AD username/password), while they are logged into SFDC (through existing SSO).

Questions - Can I leverage the existing SSO setup for this ? If not, can i call ADFS from a VF page synchronously ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish but take a look at Identity Connect, it may do what you're looking for out of the box.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.identityImplGuide.meta/identityImplGuide/identityconnect_about.htm